# Implicitly casting to bool?

Tags: gcc, c++11, casting, implicit

I'm having this strange issue with my code where it seems as if the compiler is implicitly casting my argument to another type. However when I tag the constructor as explicit, it didn't seem to fix the issue.

I have this in my unit test

```
JsonValue stringItem("test");
CHECK(stringItem.type() == JsonValue::Type::String);
```

This fails with the result

```
4 == 3
```

These are what the constructors look like...

```
JsonValue::JsonValue()
 : mType(Type::Null) {
}

JsonValue::JsonValue(bool ab)
 : mType(Type::Boolean) {
    mData.b = ab;
}

JsonValue::JsonValue(int ai)
 : mType(Type::Int) {
    mData.i = ai;
}

JsonValue::JsonValue(std::uint32_t aui)
 : mType(Type::UnsignedInt) {
    mData.ui = aui;
}

// It should be using this constructory
// but mType is not getting set to Type::String
JsonValue::JsonValue(const std::string &astr)
 : mType(Type::String) {
    mData.str = new std::string(astr);
}
```

As I mentioned before, tagging `JsonValue(bool)` as `explicit` didn't fix the issue. I also compiled with `-Wconversion` without warnings

Enum looks like this

```
enum Type {
            Null = 0,
            Object,
            Array,
            String,
            Boolean,
            Int,
            UnsignedInt
         };
```

Comment: This is kind of bizarre.. you did add the `explicit` tag in the header, not in the constructor body? For good measure can you post a complete program so that we can compile it unchanged?

Comment: Here is a runnable version: http://ideone.com/qA6Whv

Comment: I did use a ligtweight wrapper arount `bool` type called `struct Bool` as member of my discriminated union instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be explicit about the argument to the constructor:

```
JsonValue stringItem(std::string("test"));
```

What is happening is that you are getting an implicit conversion from `const char*` to `bool`, because this is a conversion between built-in types, and a better match than the conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`, which is a conversion involving a built-in type.

Alternatively, you can add a constructor that takes `const char*` and stores a string internally. This is a better option because it avoids the easy to make error you encountered:

```
JsonValue::JsonValue(const char* astr)
 : mType(Type::String) {
    mData.str = new std::string(astr);
}
```

Note that on the surface these seems to be no reason to store a dynamically allocated string. This probably adds unnecessary complications.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to store pointers because of circular dependency issues between JsonValue and JsonObject/JsonArray. And I'm storing the data in a union

Comment: @rcapote That may be a reason to store `JsonArray` and/or `JsonObject` pointer, [but storing `std::string` by value works just fine](http://ideone.com/D0RqQp).

Comment: @Casey Ah okay, thanks for the tip. One less thing I have to keep track of

Comment: @Casey I took a closer look at your example...what is `::new (&mData.str) std::string(astr);` doing? Never seen that construct before

Comment: @rcapote "placement new" - it constructs a `std::string` in the memory pointed at by `&mData.str`. You can skip construction of the fundamental types since they are trivial and simply assign them, as you do in the other constructors, but `std::string` has non-trivial construction. I could (and probably should) have achieved the same effect by [adding a string constructor to the union type instead](http://ideone.com/3kI5Nz).